# Am having migration failure each time i added a field to my class. aspnet core 3.1, MVC

Tags: migration

Am having migration failure each time i added a field to my class. aspnet core 3.1, MVC. Below is the screen

PM> add-migration initial5
Build started...
Build failed.
PM>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved, i removed other projects that were opened along with the project of interest. I equally ensured that the project built completely before running the migration.